# In Sabre - Hotel List rest API

Tags: rest, sabre

Is there any parameter to get response of Hotel List based on Country or State or City or Hotel name wise

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is based on the API you use.
In the case of **GetHotelAvailRQ** API for hotel search, you would use GeoSearch tag which has CityCode, CountryCode, and StateCode Parameters in the request for getting Hotel Response List.